# How to connect to Openstack Swift using boto3

Tags: boto3, openstack

I'm trying to connect to OpenStack Swift using boto3. I need to list all objects in a particular bucket. Using boto2 I can do this,

```
parsed = urlparse.urlparse(cloud_url)
conn = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id=cloud_user,
                       aws_secret_access_key=cloud_password,
                       port=parsed.port,
                       host=parsed.hostname,
                       is_secure=False,
                       calling_format=boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat())

buckets = conn.get_all_buckets()
for key in buckets:
    # This prints a list of bucket names.
    print key
```

But doing the same thing in boto3,

```
session = boto3.Session()
s3 = session.resource(service_name='s3',
                  use_ssl=False,
                  verify=False,
                  endpoint_url=cloud_url,
                  aws_access_key_id=cloud_user,
                  aws_secret_access_key=cloud_password)

print(list(s3.buckets.all()))
```

I'm getting an error,

> An error occurred (401) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Unauthorized

I cannot perform any operations on the endpoint using boto3, but I'm using the same access key and secret key.

Is there something else that needs to be set when using boto3?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

```py
import boto3
import botocore
boto3.set_stream_logger(name='botocore')  # this enables debug tracing
session = boto3.session.Session()
s3_client = session.client(
    service_name='s3',
    aws_access_key_id='ACCESS',
    aws_secret_access_key='SECRET',
    endpoint_url='https://YOUR.ENDPOINT.HOST/',
    # The next option is only required because my provider only offers "version 2"
    # authentication protocol. Otherwise this would be 's3v4' (the default, version 4).
    config=botocore.client.Config(signature_version='s3'),
)

s3_client.list_objects(Bucket='bucket_name')
```

For the benefit of others: note that `ACCESS` and `SECRET` are **not** the same as your Swift username and password; instead they are "EC2-style" credentials generated with the following command, after authenticating to a specific project (you need a so-called "scoped token" in your environment variables):

```
openstack ec2 credentials create
```

Also check this page for what features are supported by the S3 compatibility layer of OpenStack Swift: https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/s3_compat.html